# How to change coverage report Source File

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, lcov

Here is my project tree :

```
src
  - main
   - js
     - common
       -utils.js
       -common.js
     - api.js
  - test
    - test.js
- gruntfile.js
- target
  - work
    -coverage-reports
     -lcov.info
```

when the coverage report is generated in my lcov.info file I have something like:

```
SF: src/main/js/common/utils.js
...
...
SF: src/main/js/common/common.js
...
...
```

and as sonar properties I have :

```
-Dsonar.sources=src/main
-Dsonar.test=src/test
```

so the SF in lcov.info and sonar.sources propertie is confusing, and sonar can't find the source files

**so my question is how to precise the coverage report lcov.info How can I change the SF ??** and make it something like :

```
    SF: main/js/common/utils.js
    ...
    ...
    SF: main/js/common/common.js
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Which tool do you use to generate report?

Comment: May be you should just change the directory from where you build report to "src/main"?